# Quotient of the ring of Laurent polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field.

I want to express the ring that contains only Laurent polynomials $$P(X)=\displaystyle\sum_{i\geq 0} p_iX^i + \displaystyle\sum_{j> 0}p_{-j}X^{-j}\in K[X^{\pm 1}]$$ with the constraint $p_i\neq -p_i \forall i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}.$

Put another way, I would like the ring of Laurent polynomials modulo the polynomials $g(X)$, such that $g(X)=-g(X^{-1})$.

Can we write the desired ring as a quotient of $K[X^{\pm 1}]$?

Comment: I also don't think that the negation of $p_i\ne p_{-i}$ for all $i\ge1$ is $g(X)=-g(X^{-1})$.

Comment: @user26857 sorry for sloppiness, let me try to clear that up. Let $g(X)\in K[X^{\pm 1}]$. If $g(X)=-g(X^{-1})$ then $g(X)=\displaystyle\sum_{i\geq 1} g_i X^i + \displaystyle\sum_{i\geq 1} -g_i X^{-i}$.

Comment: I don't think the set you describe is an ideal : $X-\frac{1}{X}$ is contained in it but $X^2-1$ is not.